# Exporting a module in Node.js is causing an error

Tags: node.js, express, module, export

I am trying to get my head around the different ways you can export modules in Node.js and am running into an issue.

When exporting a module in node.js, the following works fine:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

//Verify token
exports.cookieJwtAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.token
    try {
        const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.AUTH_SECRET)
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (err) {
        res.clearCookie('token')
        return res.redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

However, when I try to export it like below I get this error:
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

//Verify token
const cookieJwtAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.token
    try {
        const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.AUTH_SECRET)
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (err) {
        res.clearCookie('token')
        return res.redirect('/login')
    }
}

module.exports = cookieJwtAuth
```

Why is the second code sample throwing the error, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
module.exports = {cookieJwtAuth}
```

to match it with the first code

Comment: Thank you Alexander, that did the trick :)